# Solving $\frac{8^x-2^x}{6^x-3^x} = 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$\frac{8^x-2^x}{6^x-3^x} = 2$

I was able to use difference of cubes on the numerator, and setting $a= 2^x$ would give the following:

$\frac{a(a-1)(a+1)}{3^x(a-1)} = 2$

Now we have a common factor and with $a \not= 1$. Then I moved on to express the $3^x$ term in terms of $2^x$ to get like terms on both sides. This would yield:

$a(a+1) = 2(3^x)$

$a(a+1) = 2(2^{(log_2(3))})^x$

$a(a+1) = 2(a^{(log_2(3))})$

$a+1 = 2a^{(log_2(\frac{3}{2}))}$

Here is where I am stuck, is there an algebraic way to continue this method until we get the answer?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your approach makes sense but the problem is that, in fact, your approach shows that you can't solve the equation in question algebraically. You'll have to use analytic tools. For example, just guessing yields that $x=0$ (once you take the $6^x-3^x$ to the other side) and $x=1$ works, and you can show that there aren't any other solutions using calculus, for example.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer How does x=0 work? Doesn’t that give you 0/0?

Comment: Check [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699669/frac8x-2x6x-3x-2-solve-for-x).

Comment: @Divide1918 You're right, I realized that afterwards, and I was considering the equation $8^x-2^x = 2(6^x-3^x)$ instead for which $x=0$ is a solution. Indeed, $x=1$ is the only solution of that equation.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak thanks for this, looks like someone already asked this :)

Comment: You're welcome @ShootingStars!

Comment: So we can close this as a duplicate of [$\frac{8^x-2^x}{6^x-3^x}=2$, Solve for $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699669/frac8x-2x6x-3x-2-solve-for-x)